# Is there a way I can have items in divs rearange to fit the space available?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of dummy data in Bootstrap column all inside one row inside a fluid container.

Here's what my code looks like (cut out a lot of content that's not needed):

```
<div id="container" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <div>
                Data here!
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
            <div>
                Data here!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyway, when adding a lot of different columns with different sizes, it quickly becomes a huge mess.

---

This image shows what it looks like (and the arrows show where stuff could go to fill up the whole page):

[image]

---

Am I using the wrong approach for this? Is there a simpler way to "fit everything?" Is there any jQuery code to fix this? I tried Googling this a few times, but I don't know the keywords for this. I'm curious if there's any solution to this problem. You don't ever see anything like this... most social media sites have fixed width with multiple columns. I'm getting a ton of content from a quarter of a page to five words, so it doesn't always work best to do it that way.

I can't build something on the server side because this is going to be responsive and things will load different sizes based on screen size. The order of items doesn't matter within the row. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masonry or Packery.
Packery has more features but is heavier.

http://masonry.desandro.com/

http://packery.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Possible, You can rearrange the grids/Divs as like you mentioned in your image. firstly you should be completely aware of Bootstrap Grid System [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

I will explain briefly.

Bootstrap provide us a facility to specify a `row` inside a `col-xs-*` class, by doing this you will get another 12 grids inside the `col-xs-*` and this 12 grids can be splitted into the way you want. below picture speaks more about it.

[image: Grid system]

So by tuning your HTML Code you can achieve the layout in a way you want. below is the HTML Code for the layout mentioned in the picture.

```
div id="container" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div>Data here!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div>Data here!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div>Data here!</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div>Data here!</div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div>Data here!</div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-xs-8">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-4">
                       <div>Data here!</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xs-4">
                       <div>Data here!</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-xs-4">
                       <div>Data here!</div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-xs-2">
               <div>Data here!</div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is recommended that do not overflow the 12 grids inside a `row` class. for a better layout design you can always use the 12 grids inside a `row` class or you can leave the grids empty. it's up to you

Once you get a complete idea about the grid system, GUI Layouts will be very handy with Bootstrap

Good Day !!!

Comment: +1! I'll definitely keep this in mind when working with manual layouts as this is helpful. However, I'm getting content dynamically and can't mess around with it manually, so it looks like a library would be a better choice...